# Possible With WebStorm and JavaScript to extract a class compponent to separate file?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I have a class component in react that I refactored out of the render method and it looks like the following inside my index.js file.

```
    class speakerCard extends Component {
        render() {
            return <div>
                <img className="card-img-top" src={`/static/speakers/Speaker-${this.props.speaker.id}.jpg`}/>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary margintopbottom10">Details</a>
                    <h4 className="card-title">{this.props.speaker.firstName} {this.props.speaker.lastName} </h4>
                    <p className="card-text">{this.props.speaker.bioShort}</p>

                </div>
            </div>;
        }
    }
```

Is there any nice refactoring in WebStorm that let's me pull this out directly to it's own file? (SpeakerCard.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On class name, hit `F6` (or choose **Refactor > Move...** from right-click menu), specify a file to move the class to:

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you @lena